# Sylius / Symfony cannot find new console generated bundles

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

We're working with Sylius and trying to create new bundles.  Through the console using **php bin/console generate:bundle** a new bundle is easily createable.  however when we try to run the site we get the error: **ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 36:**  We are registering our new bundle in the **AppKernel.php** file, and editing the **composer.json** file to autoload the new bundle but nothing seems to work.  We have tried every solution mentioned on SO without luck.  Can anyone point us in the right direction?

MUCH APPRECIATED-!

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        new \Sylius\Bundle\AdminBundle\SyliusAdminBundle(),
        new \Sylius\Bundle\ShopBundle\SyliusShopBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle(),
        new \FOS\OAuthServerBundle\FOSOAuthServerBundle(), // Required by SyliusApiBundle
        new \Sylius\Bundle\ApiBundle\SyliusApiBundle(),
        new \AppBundle\AppBundle(),

        //NEW BUNDLE
        new TGB\AmazonBundle\AmazonBundle(),

    ];

    return array_merge(parent::registerBundles(), $bundles);
}
```

from our **composer.json** file

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle/",
        "TGB\\AmazonBundle\\": "src/TGB/AmazonBundle/"
    },
    "classmap": ["app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php"]
},
```

Comment: This is the rest of the error message we recieve...  **Attempted to load class "AmazonBundle" from namespace "TGB\AmazonBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?**

Comment: Note: i have also tried creating a new bundle manually and the same issues arise.  The folder structure and namespace match the default AppBundle exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, we needed to run **composer dump-autoload** it was caching and wouldn't go look for the new classes that it needed to load.